# Can't split a date-time column without it converting to character

Tags: r, date, time, posixct

```
head(my_df)
# A tibble: 6 x 5

     ID Name               Type  Function   Date_time          
  <dbl> <chr>              <chr> <chr>      <dttm>       

1     1 Look Away          1v3   teg        1899-12-31 00:00:43
2     1 Bobsled Run        2v2   teg        1899-12-31 00:01:32
3     1 Give me a Break!   item  additional 1899-12-31 00:00:20
4     1 Shock Drop or Roll 3v1   teg        1899-12-31 00:00:23
5     1 Move to the Music  3v1   teg        1899-12-31 00:00:47
6     1 Bowl Over          3v1   teg        1899-12-31 00:00:41
```

I am trying to separate the Date_time column into two columns: Date and Time.

First I tried to separate the two using:

```
my_df %>% separate(“Date_time”, into = c("Date", "Time"), sep = " = ")
```

but it turned both into character vectors, which means I can't add/use the contents.

I looked around on stack overflow and found this solution for extracting the time, but it also converts the new column to character. Here is the code:

```
head(my_df)

# A tibble: 6 x 5
     ID Name               Type  Function   Date_time          
  <dbl> <chr>              <chr> <chr>      <dttm>             
1     1 Look Away          1v3   teg        1899-12-31 00:00:43
2     1 Bobsled Run        2v2   teg        1899-12-31 00:01:32
3     1 Give me a Break!   item  additional 1899-12-31 00:00:20
4     1 Shock Drop or Roll 3v1   teg        1899-12-31 00:00:23
5     1 Move to the Music  3v1   teg        1899-12-31 00:00:47
6     1 Bowl Over          3v1   teg        1899-12-31 00:00:41

> my_df$Time <- format(as.POSIXct(my_df$Date_time), format = "%H:%M:%S")
> head(my_df)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
    ID Name               Type  Function   Date_time           Time    
  <dbl> <chr>              <chr> <chr>      <dttm>              <chr>   
1     1 Look Away          1v3   teg        1899-12-31 00:00:43 00:00:43
2     1 Bobsled Run        2v2   teg        1899-12-31 00:01:32 00:01:32
3     1 Give me a Break!   item  additional 1899-12-31 00:00:20 00:00:20
4     1 Shock Drop or Roll 3v1   teg        1899-12-31 00:00:23 00:00:23
5     1 Move to the Music  3v1   teg        1899-12-31 00:00:47 00:00:47
6     1 Bowl Over          3v1   teg        1899-12-31 00:00:41 00:00:41
```

As you can see, the new Time column is now a character vector. How do I do this while keeping it a dttm (or preferably, just a time object)

Thanks,

Jim

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: There is not "just a time object" in R, in general. There are some ways around this using `lubridate` that encode a "time" as a decimal-day (meaning high-noon is 0.5), but it isn't directly comparable with `POSIXt` objects (in which "1" is a second, not a day). Realize that you can always change the way a `POSIXt` object is *displayed* using `format(x, "%H:%M:%S")`.

Comment: So I tried to change the display using my_df$Time <- format(my_df$Date_time, "%H:%M:%S") but it still changed it into a character vector. I want to have it appear in hms but still be able to find the mean/sum etc. of it.

Comment: You can use `IDateTime` from `data.table` package, e.g. `IDateTime("1899-12-31 00:00:43")`. `IDateTime` creates a column of class `IDate` (which "has the same internal representation as the `Date` class, except the storage mode is integer") and a column of class `ITime`, "a time-of-day class stored as the integer number of seconds in the day."

Comment: Thanks r2evans and Henrik. I got it.